# Extract numbers from cells containing mixed text

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vba, macros

If I have these in column A:

```
   A

 om2222prakash 264737 suman 278
 kumar83566$ 267863; ravi0202;%43
 222gsranasjgjhjs56 djhdjdj58
 k4566hhhh23
 28.5ʺW × 33.0ʺD × 37.0ʺH
 W51.77 x D40.04 x H31.49
 W29.13 x D32.67 x H35.05
```

How can I find out only numeric data in A1, A2, A3 and A4? I am using Microsoft Excel 2010, and would like to have the output look like this in column B:

```
  B

2222,264737,278
83566,267863,0202,43
222,56,58
4566,23
28.5,33.0,37.0
51.77,40.04,31.49
29.13,32.67,35.05
```

Comment: I can't see a way to do this with Excel's inbuilt functions, but it's straightforward in VBA, as described [here](http://analystcave.com/excel-regex-tutorial/). If you don't know VBA or Regular Expressions, then you won't find it easy, but I don't know of a simpler solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [regex find/replace addin](http://www.codedawn.com/excel-add-ins.php) to gain regular expression functionality in Excel.
*(I'm not connected to that tool in any way, just an enthusiastic user.)*

There you can use `RegExReplace` function:

- `=RegExReplace(A1,"[^0-9]+",",")` to replace all non numeric content to `,`
- `=RegExReplace(B1,"^,?(.+[^,]),?$","$1")` to remove leading and trailing `,`

Or in one formula:
`=RegExReplace(RegExReplace(A2,"[^0-9]+",","),"^,?(.+[^,]),?$","$1")`

[image]

### Update

To manage decimal numbers correctly, you need to slightly modify formula:

- Keep only numbers and `.`:
  `=RegExReplace(A1,"[^0-9.]+",",")`
- Additional step: remove all `.` not part of a number:
  `=RegExReplace(B1,"[,.]{2,}",",")`
- Last step remains the same:
  `=RegExReplace(C1,"^,?(.+[^,]),?$","$1")`

Comment: If my input of 25.0ʺW × 40.0ʺD × 36.0ʺH 28.5ʺW × 33.5ʺD × 37.0ʺH and i have need output of-> 25.0,40.0,36.0 28.5,33.5,37.0

Comment: Please edit your question,  so I can update my answer.

Comment: i have edit my question please  suggest..